# PHP Recursive function not working as expected :(

Tags: php, function, recursion, file-get-contents

I have the following codes and they are not working:

index.php:

```
    include("loadData.php");
    $my_var = loadData("myTxt.txt");
    var_dump($my_var);
```

loadData.php:

```
    function loadData($my_file){
       if(file_exists($my_file)){
          $file_contents = file_get_contents($my_file);
          $file_contents = json_decode($file_contents);
       }else{
          // If file doesn't exist, creates the file and runs the function again
          $data_to_insert_into_file = simplexml_load_file("http://site_with_content.com");
          $fp = fopen($my_file, "w");
          fwrite($fp, json_encode($data_to_insert_into_file));
          fclose($fp);
          // Since the file is created I will call the function again
          loadData($my_file);
          return;
       }

       // Do things with the decoded file contents (this is suposed to run after the file is loaded)
       $result = array();
       $result = $file_contents['something'];
       return $result;
    }
```

This works as expected in the second time (after the file is created), I can display info on index.php, but in the first time I run (before the file is created) it always displays $result as NULL, I can't understand why since I call the function again...

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Fix your return statements to return correct values ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return anything when you do your fetch:

```
if (...) {
   $file_contents = file_get_contents(...);
   // no return call here
} else {
   ...
   return; // return nothing, e.g. null
}
return $result; // $result is NEVER set in your code
```

You should have `return $file_contents`. Or better yet:

```
if (...) {
   $result = get cached data
} else {
   $result = fetch/get new data
}
return $result;
```

by using the proper variable names everywhere.

Comment: I have edited the function, I forgot to write the last two lines before the return $result!

Comment: you still don't return ANYTHING from your fetch/fwrite section, you simply `return;`, which means the calling context gets a null value.

Comment: But when I call the function again won't I exit the "current" function? (Stop the current operation)

Comment: no. and why are you doing this recursively anyways? There is **NO** point in fetching the file, writing it to disk, and then calling the function AGAIN just to read the exact same data from disk.

Comment: I don't want to bother the site again, now that I have the file I want to load it from my own server.

How would you do it?

Thank you.

Comment: don't even bother recursing. `if (file_exists() { return data from file } else { fetch data from site, write data to file, return data }` only if the file doesn't exist do you hit the site.

Comment: Why shouldn't this be recursive? I still don't get it sorry.

Comment: because you already HAVE your text when you fetch it from the site and write it to disk. it's like having a chocolate bar in your hand and deciding to go back to the store to buy another chocolate bar. just eat the one you already have.

Comment: No, in the first time that I run the function the file never exist, $my_file is dynamic.

Comment: so? You fetch the data into a variable, you write to file from that variable. That data is *STILL* in the same variable you fetched it into, so just return from that.

Comment: I do alot of things with the decoded data after the return, I will rethink this function.